# UICollectionViewCell is not rounding corners inside UITableView

Tags: swift, xcode

The problem is that when I have `UICollectionView` inside `UITableViewCell` - `UICollectionViewCell` cornerRadius function not working.

Code is very simple and it was always working for me when playing with `UICollectionView`.

```
extension ExploreTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ExploreCollectionViewCell
    
    cell.thumbnail.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    cell.thumbnail.clipsToBounds = true
    
    return cell
}
```

Is it a bug or what? Cannot find any answer all day. Most of the people suggest to use contentView instead of the specific image inside the cell but that's not for me since I want **only** image to be rounded.

P.S this one works (but I want only image inside the cell to be rounded):

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

Comment: In the cell, add an extra view to be the image view's superview (inside the content view) and round that.

Comment: @matt just tried your solution. Added extra view which is superview for my image (inside the content view) and tried to round it but no results..

Comment: Darn. Even when you also set its `clipsToBounds`?

Comment: Maybe try reloadingData on the collectionView after the cells configure? It might be a loading/timing issue between the 2 views.

Comment: @purebreadd Tried to reloadData but no results

Comment: @matt Alright just fixed this issue. I don't know why but when making my image constraints not equal widths and heights to the contentView then rounded corners work (also image is smaller than the contentView now).